# How to make an endless route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

How to make an endless route?

I have an unknown nesting, following which we need to display it in the route, for example

```
Folder url.com/folder
-Child 1 url.com/folder/child1
--Child 2 url.com/folder/child1/child2
---Child 3 url.com/folder/child1/child2/child3
---- Child 4 url.com/folder/child1/child2/child3/child4
...

<Route path="folder">
  <ComponentExample />
</Route>
```

How to determine the route if the nesting is unknown?

Answer (score 1):

Use the current segment, e.g. "directory", followed by the `"*"` wildcard character to indicate that anything after the segment can also be matched.

```
const RootComponent = {
  ...

  return (
    <Routes>
      ...
      <Route path="/folder/*" element={<ComponentExample />} />
      ...
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

This routed component then renders ***descendent*** routes relative to this parent path.

```
const ComponentExample = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <Routes>
      ...
      <Route path="child1/*" element={<Child1 />} /> // <-- "/folder/child1/*
      ...
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

And so on until you finally reach a leaf node that *doesn't* render another set of descendent routes.

If you just intend to render this same `ComponentExample` for *any* `"/folder/*` then you can use just this as the path and use the [splat](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats) to get the rest of the path.

```
const RootComponent = {
  ...

  return (
    <Routes>
      ...
      <Route path="/folder/*" element={<ComponentExample />} />
      ...
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ComponentExample = () => {
  const { "*": splat } = useParams();
  console.log(splat); // "child1", "child1/child2", "child1/child2/child3", etc
  ...

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **react-router-dom** v5+, just set **path=folder/***, the router will match every route starting with **folder/**