# How can I have an undefined numbers of multiple dynamic path segments in a route in React that point to the same component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I need to have a route that can receive many different path segments dynamically like `"https://website/folder1/folder2/folder3"` and so on.

Each time a user can create a new folder inside another folder and can be navigated to the same component.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to create a page like Google drive with a folders and subfolders system, where an user can create a folder and subfolders inside it and upload documents and videos and other users can see them when they go in the nested specific folder. In order to keep track of the location of the user and get the right documents/files to show from the server I was thinking to use the url to get the last path segment to know what data I need to ask the server, I also need the full path for a breadcrumb.

I found some sources around that suggested using `"+"` after the id path segment but it is not working:

```
<Route path="/area/:folder+" element={<AreaComponent />} />
```

The problem is this doesn't work.

I am using `react-router-dom@6.4.2`.

How can I implement this?

Comment: React-Router v6 removed support for REGEXP in the route paths. You could use `path="/area/*"` and then grab the rest of the path from the splat. Can you [edit] to clarify better the use case? Do you need to do anything with the path segments later?

Comment: You could use `path="/area/:folder*"` with asterisk, and then split the "folder" param by slash to get the different folders

Comment: @DrewReese yes, I edit the question to make it more clear. I tried your solution and it works. I can get the url with useLocation, split by the slash and take what I need. Do you have other suggestions how to better handle what I am trying to achieve after my update on the main topic?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76863200/8690857? Recursively render descendent routes that "sip" the first path segment (*and name it*) and render the rest of the path with trailing `"*"`?

Comment: @DrewReese exactly that! I for sure didn't use the appropriate keyword when I was searching for answer. Didn't think about the endless keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-Router v6 removed support for REGEXP in the route paths. You could use `path="/area/*"` and then grab the rest of the path from the splat.

```
<Route path="/area/*" element={<AreaComponent />} />
```

Example URL: `"https://website/area/folder1/folder2/folder3"`

AreaComponent

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { "*": splat } = useParams();
console.log(splat); // "folder1/folder2/folder3"
```

From here you can use simple string manipulation to handle/extract information from the rest of the path.

See route [Splats](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In React Router version 6, dynamic nested routes can be a bit different to set up compared to previous versions. The + syntax you mentioned is not used in the same way as in previous versions. Instead, React Router v6 uses a * to capture multiple segments.

```
<Route path="/area/*" element={<AreaComponent />} />
```

you can access the captured segments using the useParams

```
const { '*': folders } = useParams();
const folderNames = folders.split('/');
```